# C++ Получение параметров из url используя cgi

Tags: c++, url, cgi

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне получить параметры которые я задал в своём url чтобы далее их использовать в программе

Вот пока что мой код на C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "triangle.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
    cout << "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Lab3</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
    cout << "<body link='#FF9900' vlink='#FF9900' alink='#FF9900'>\n";
    cout << "<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1251'>\n";
    cout << "<p style='line-height:100%; margin-left:10%;' align='center'><span style='font-size:14pt;'>Cgi-скрипт на С++.</span></p>\n";

    char comment[256];


    int number_of_chars = GetEnvironmentVariable(L"QUERY_STRING", (LPWSTR)comment, 256);
```

Запускаю cgi скрипт вот так: localhost/{путь к скрипту}?a=2,b=3

Comment: Преобразование `(LPWSTR)comment` и указанный размер буфера некорректны, буфер следует заводить в wchar_t. А возвращаемое значение имеет тип `DWORD`, а не int

Comment: А как далее мне получить параметры a, b (пример url: localhost/{путь к скрипту}?a=2,b=3)? Вы можете пожалуйста привести в пример часть кода?

Comment: Ну если строку получили, то распарсить ее уже не должно быть проблемой.